# With Java AOT compilation (jaotc) is obfuscation required?

Tags: java, aot

From [JEP-295](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295), I don't see any options to disable or enable debug symbols in the produced native executables.

I would like to know if I should keep obfuscating my class files before calling jaotc. Normally, when you produce a native executable it's all binary executable and there is no need to do any obfuscation, except when debug symbols are preserved.

Is obfuscation required with Java AOT compilation (jaotc)?

Comment: Obfuscation is pretty much useless no matter what you're doing.

Comment: @Kayaman, why is obfuscation useless?

Comment: Because it provides protection only from people you don't need protection from (I suppose it still has some relevance in shrinking mobile builds, although I'm not very up to date on mobile development any more).